# В IntelliJ, как исправить "эти файлы не принадлежат проекту"?

Tags: java

При создании любого проекта(так как я учу java то создаю просто с шаблоном) появляется ошибка. Уже долго не могу решить проблему. ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА все что нашел в интернете - не получилось.[image: вот проблема]

Comment: Просто откройте папку 1 через меню File-Open

Comment: это не решает проблему

Comment: Удалите все файлы iml в папке 1 и попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: не помогло. все также но без iml файлов